# Is it correct to say "can you forward my profile to the hiring manager to see if there is any interest in moving forward"

Tags: grammar, word-usage, word-choice

I am emailing a recruiter to ask if they can forward my profile and my resume to the hiring manager to see if that hiring manager is willing to move forward with my candidacy.

I wonder if it is correct to say:

> can you forward my profile to the hiring manager to see if there is any interest in moving forward?

Or should it be "there is **an** interest"?

Comment: "Can" asks if the person is *able* to do the task. "Would you please," is a *request* to do so. As for "any" vs. "an", both are correct, but I'd avoid "any" lest it seem like one is unsure the CV would be of interest to anyone.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik you mean in this case I should've used "would you please" instead of "can" right?

Comment: In a formal letter, yes, or a similar phrase. Colloquially, "can" might be acceptable.

Comment: "Can you..." is a totally standard way to make a request. It's not very formal though, so it would depend on the relationship you have with the recruiter

Comment: @gotube Personally, even if it were the first time I were working with the recruiter, I would find this kind of casual address pretty normal.

Comment: @Casey Yes, in the English-speaking world. We don't know how familiar a relationship people have with recruiters in the OP's country though.

Comment: @gotube The profile says he’s in Canada.

Comment: I get what @DrMoishePippik is saying about "can", but in practice, in American English, people say "can" in this context all the time. In my experience, it's only very pedantic English teachers who object to it. Like when I was a little boy in school, teachers had a regular routine that if a child asked, "Can I go to the bathroom?" the teacher would answer, "I don't know. Can you? Or did you intend to ask, 'May I?'" Cute, but it got old real fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In context, "any interest" and "an interest" mean essentially the same thing. Few would notice any difference.

In the United States, we would not say "my profile". No one talks about a "profile" for a job application. We'd just say "my resume". If you really wanted to be complete you could say "my resume and cover letter", but it would really be unnecessary to specify that as it would normally be assumed. "Profile" makes it sound like you're on an on-line dating app, not applying for a job! All that said, I'm speaking about US usage. If you're in some other English-speaking country, usage might be different.

Comment: I had assumed that was a LinkedIn profile when I saw it the first time.  If not I agree that it is strange.

Comment: @casey Fair enough. We do routinely talk about "profiles" on a web site, so if you were talking about Linkedin or some other job-hunting-related site, that would make sense.

Answer (score 1):

It is correct. “Any” interest or “an” interest would both be fine and it doesn’t change the meaning at all in this instance. I do not agree with the comments you’ve received suggesting you replace “can” with “would you please,” because I think that is too formal for this context. However, I’m in the US and preferences might differ here on a regional basis.